# Can I use "have" and "had" in one sentence, like "I have had my revenge at last"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-usage

'I have had my revenge at last.' -what kind of sentence is this?
Can I use have and had in one sentence?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey. ["Present" perfect](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect)?

Comment: What do you mean by "kind" of sentence? Are you asking about tense or clause structure, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [present perfect tense](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/).

These examples may help you understand the structure better:

*She **has been** a teacher for 30 years.* (Your main verb is "to be".)
*I **have seen** him a few times.* (Your main verb is "to see".)
*He **has worked** for this company since 2010.* (Your main verb is "to work".)
*I **have had** this car for 10 years* (Your main verb is "to have".)

Comment: Actually, it's the first verb ("has/have") that is the matrix (your main) verb in each sentence. "Been a teacher" / "seen him ..." / "worked for ..." / "had this car" are subordinate clauses, each with its own verb. The clauses function as complement of the matrix verbs.